# Looping through lines in csv file with bash

Tags: bash, csv, while-loop

How come this while loop only executes once even though there are 2 entries (lines) in the .csv file?
And how come when no files/directories match the expression, the string 'ls: /root/*heapdump*: No such file or directory' is output to console also?

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=targets.csv

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while IFS=, read target user password path
do
    result=$(sshpass -p "$password" ssh "$user"@"$target" ls "$path"*heapdump*)

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
            echo "No Heap dumps detected."
    else
            echo "Found a Heap dump! Possible OOM issue detected"
    fi

done < $INPUT
```

.csv contents ..

```
rob@laptop:~/scripts$ cat targets.csv 
server.com,root,passw0rd,/root/
server.com,root,passw0rd,/root/
```

Output ..

```
rob@laptop:~/scripts$ ./checkForHeapdump.sh 
ls: /root/*heapdump*: No such file or directory
No Heap dumps detected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` is reading from stdin, so it's slurping up the rest of the CSV file during the first iteration. Change to:

```
result=$(sshpass -p "$password" ssh -n "$user"@"$target" ls "$path"*heapdump*)
```

The `-n` option redirects `ssh` stdin to `/dev/null`.

Regarding the error message, that's the normal error output when you do:

```
ls filename-or-wildcard
```

and there are no matches. If you don't want to see that, redirect stderr:

```
result=$(sshpass -p "$password" ssh -n "$user"@"$target" ls "$path"*heapdump* 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the final line of your CSV file is not terminated with a carriage return.

When this happens `read` will populate the variables but without the carriage return to terminate the line it will instead reach the end of file and so the loop will not execute.

If you cannot confirm the final line will be terminated with a carriage return, and are unable to edit the file by putting `echo >> targets.csv` at the start of the script to add one, then you can check the variables after the loop to act on them.  To do this I would clear one of the variables at the end of the loop so then you can simply test whether it is non-zero length to know there is one final unprocessed line.